# Execute a script whenever Linux Mint resumes from suspend

Tags: linux, linux-mint, suspend

I'm running Linux Mint. I have a script the gets run whenever I login that remaps my mouse buttons. However, when the computer suspends, the mouse buttons revert to their default mapping.

I'd like to have my script re-run whenever the computer awakes from suspend. How can I do this? Currently I'm just calling the script from the "Startup Applications" control panel.

I already tried putting some copies of my script in subdirectories within `/etc/pm`, but that didn't work.

EDIT: Actually when my computer comes out of suspend, sometimes the mouse mapping hasn't been reset. But when I turn the monitors off, then back on (using their power buttons) the mouse mapping has always been reset. How can I prevent this? (Or where can I put a script so it will run when the monitors turn back on?)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the reason why your script "doesn't work" is due to several reasons:

- The script is not executable. It should be executable (run `chmod +x` on it).
- The script is running as root when the system reboots (I think). To run it as your user, try something like:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> case "$1" in
>       hibernate|suspend)
>           sudo -u USERNAME env DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info --text "do stuff on suspend"
>           ;;
>       thaw|resume)
>           sudo -u USERNAME env DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info --text "do stuff on resume"
>           ;;
>           esac

(stolen shamelessly from [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/209855/69511)).

Obviously you can replace the `zenity` call with the action you want to take when resuming from suspend. `USERNAME` should be the user you're normally logged in as (if this changes a lot, that could get complicated).

Comment: It's executable. I added `sudo -u` but that didn't fix it, though clearly I needed to add that---just forget to include that before. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: +1 for showing thaw|resume  - the template script I was looking for only had thaw, and I needed resume to get out of a sleep, rather then suspend state.